# Cross Origin requests are disallowed on Safari when Basic authentication is enabled

Tags: apache, https, safari, cors, basic-authentication

I've encountered this problem which only seems to affect Safari (11.1). The same code runs fine on Firefox and Chrome.
I was experimenting with making cross domain Ajax requests when basic HTTP authentication is enabled (on both sites). Https is also enabled. I'm using Apache 2.4.29 on a Macbook Pro.

The set up is that I have two test sites running on my local machine,  foo.com and bar.com. foo.com makes an Ajax request for a json file that resides on bar.com. As stated, all communication takes place over https which I set up with a self-signed certificate.

Here is my Apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName foo.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/foo"
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/foo-error-log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/foo-access-log" common
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/certificates/foo/foo.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/certificates/foo/foo.key"
  <Directory "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/foo">
    AuthType Basic                            
    AuthName "Restricted Files"               
    AuthBasicProvider file                    
    AuthUserFile "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-passwords"
    Require user richard  
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName bar.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/bar"
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bar-error-log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bar-access-log" common
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/certificates/bar/bar.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/certificates/bar/bar.key"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://foo.com"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

  <Directory "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-experiment/bar">
    AuthType Basic    
    AuthName "Restricted Files"    
    AuthBasicProvider file    
    AuthUserFile "/Users/richardhunter/development/cors-passwords"
    Require user richard  
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On Safari I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Origin https://foo.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
(anonymous function)
```

If I turn off authentication on the server, then the call works. There wasn't anything more useful in the error logs.

I hope that cross-domain calls of this type are possible on Safari on a live site (not using self-signed certificates), but I don't know that to be the case. Obviously, I'd be interested to know. I would also like my local environment to replicate a live one as closely as possible.

My code is in [this Github repo](https://github.com/Richardinho/cors-with-authentication)

Comment: Please consider filing a Safari bug report at https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=WebKit